# Make Http request from a ashx to another ashx

Tags: c#

In my C# project, I have 2 web endpoints: "Start.ashx" and "Query.ashx".
And when I start my project, I can hit both endpoints like 'http://localhost/site/start.ashx?text=abc' and 'http://localhost/site/Query.asxh?text=abc'

My question is in my start.ashx, how can I create a web request to query.ashx?

One thing I can think of is doing: But I think it is better not the put localhost in my request.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://localhost/site/Query.ashx?text=abc");
```

Is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need to make a web request? If it's in the same project, call the same application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through `HttpContext` you can get the Url from the `Request` object and use it to construct your `WebRequest` URL.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string url = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    // ---- url ==> "http://localhost:21310/site/htmlpage.ashx"
    string baseUrl = context.Request.Url.Authority;
    // ---- baseUrl ==> "localhost:21310"
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://"+ baseUrl +"/site/Query.ashx?query=abc");
    // rest of the logic
}
```

However, if both endpoints are in the same project, it is not efficient to make a http request to get the data

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to create another class which contains the 'meat' of the query code, and then invoke it in both places;

```
// in QueryService.cs, you define a library for querying...
public class QueryService
{
    public DataTable PerformQuery(string searchTerm)
    {
       // your query logic goes here. Return a logical result like a DataTable, some JSON, etc.
    } 
}   

// in Query.ashx, call your query service;
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var searchTerm = context.Request.QueryString["query"];
    var results = new QueryService().PerformQuery(searchTerm);
    context.Response.Write(...results...);
}

// in Start.ashx, call your query service again;
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var searchTerm = context.QueryString["homepage"];
    var results = new QueryService().PerformQuery(searchTerm);
    context.Response.Write(...results...);
}
```

In this way, any part of your application can perform queries, with a small amount of code, without having to make another web request which is expensive, by making a standard function call.